# Does the cartodb Maps API support listing named maps in open source version?

Tags: cartodb

I have setup a local copy of cartodb, and while I can fully login to the console, I'm having trouble using the Maps API to list and modify map templates. Is this something that is supported?

Carto's official documentation on the Maps API with examples:
https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/maps-api/named-maps/

I've tried commands that have worked in the past, and am having no luck.

Command to list map templates:
curl -X GET 'https://cartotest.localhost.lan/api/v1/map/named?api_key=APIKEY'

Depending whether I try using http or https I get the responses:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to cartotest.localhost.lan port 80: Connection refused
curl: (7) Failed to connect to cartotest.localhost.lan port 443: Connection refused

Has anybody else tried this? Maybe I just have something setup wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have already posted this at the CartoDB [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/UIjDmMtohls), which is actually a better place to make this kind of questions so I think you should close this question.

Comment: Thank you Jorge! I didn't think having a redundant post on StackOverflow would be a bad idea, since it seemed to get more traffic than the cartodb group, but I will consider that going forward. The issue is resolved in the response on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/UIjDmMtohls) which he has also linked above.

Comment: Well, my point is just that for cartodb deployments, the mailing list is the best place while this or GIS Stack Exchange are better for API questions, SQL, Builder, etc. Not making a judgment, just stating the situation. Anyway, we (CARTO folks) track all of them :_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved by [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/UIjDmMtohls). Addressing the Maps API port 8181 solved the issue.